# Don't print the part name in the part's title

Tags: titlesec, parts

I have a few parts in a document of class `book`. In the part header page, I want to print the title of the book and `\partname~\thepart` only.

I am using `titlesec` to manipulate the style of this header, and I can't figure out how not to print the argument of the `\part{}` command.

In other words, I want the word "Introduction" *not* to be printed:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\title{The Book Title}
\let\thetitle\@title
\usepackage{titlesec}
  \titleformat{\part}[display]
  {}
  {\centering\huge\@title\linebreak
    \partname~\thepart}{0pt}
  {}
  []
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\part{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `before-code`  can take the title as an argument and do something with it, for example gobble it:

```
\documentclass{book}
\makeatletter
\title{The Book Title}
\let\thetitle\@title
\usepackage{titlesec}
  \titleformat{\part}[display]
  {}
  {\centering\huge\@title\linebreak
    \partname~\thepart}{0pt}
  {\@gobble}
  []
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\part{Introduction}
Lorem ipsum
\end{document}
```

Comment: Probably `\thetitle` instead of `\@title`, because using `\maketitle` would undefine `\@title`.